# How to know when computer object added to security group

Tags: security, powershell, active-directory

I need to check when one of the server in my organization is added to security group, Means which date or if possible to check who added it ? is there is any power shell command from which I can check.

Answer (score 1):

To get the information you need, you first need to make sure that you audit the changes in AD that you want. Try searching for "active directory audit security group" on google, or simply visit the first result: [Auditing Group Membership Changes in Active Directory](http://whatevernetworks.com/?p=21).

When you have enabled it, changes to accounts will be audited/logged in the Security log on the domain controllers. Now you can simply use PowerShell to search for it. Ex. if the group is a global security group, the eventid for added member is `632`. So to search for group "FOO", use:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Security -InstanceId 632 -Message "*FOO*"
```

This should (don't have a test-lab to verify with atm.) include who made the change, who was added to what group(FOO) and when it was done. The event will only show up on the domain controller that the request was sent to(!).

If you have multiple domain controllers(as you should), you should use Event Subscriptions to collect the events to a central server or your workstation. You could also use WMI-subscriptions to run a script whenever a new event like that occours. A simple search here on SO or google will show you how to do that.

**EDIT** If the person who downvoted me reads this later, could you please leave a comment with the reason. It's hard to improve when you never get feedback. The answer includes an explanation and a solution including the necessary PowerShell command, so I can't see what I did wrong.

Comment: Thank you for reply.. I tried google first then I wrote my first question here. May be I did not use the right keywords because of which Not able to find solution. Thanks again. Will try this.